# Plot of sin^2+cos^2 giving unexpected result

Tags: plotting

I'm struggling to plot this function:

```
test[t_] := Sin[t]^2 + Cos[t]^2
Plot[test[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

It gives me blank plot but should be straight line (y=1)? Its basic one but i need it for something more complex.

Thx in advance!

Comment: It plots an horizzontal line at 1, as it shoud, it is just hidden by the `t` axis. Check `Plot` documentation.

Comment: Huh...t axis? How to show it? I did, several times... will do it again. I'm missing something basic here...

Comment: and thx for quick response!

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by that? How to show that axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}`

```
test[t_] := Sin[t]^2 + Cos[t]^2
Plot[test[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Check he [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).